# Domain specific query language with Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, dsl, pyparsing

I am writing an app using Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy. I want the user to be able to be able to query the database using a domain specific query language, like `parent.name = "foo" AND (name = "bar" OR age = 11)`.

I have written a parser for this language using Pyparsing:

```
import pyparsing as pp

query = 'parent.name = "foo" AND (name = "bar" OR age = 11)'

and_operator = pp.oneOf(['and', '&'], caseless=True)
or_operator = pp.oneOf(['or', '|'], caseless=True)

identifier = pp.Word(pp.alphas + '_', pp.alphas + '_.')
comparison_operator = pp.oneOf(['=','!=','>','>=','<', '<='])

integer = pp.Regex(r'[+-]?\d+').setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0]))
float_ = pp.Regex(r'[+-]?\d+\.\d*').setParseAction(lambda t: float(t[0]))
string = pp.QuotedString('"')

comparison_operand = string | identifier | float_ | integer
comparison_expr = pp.Group(comparison_operand +
                           comparison_operator +
                           comparison_operand)

grammar = pp.operatorPrecedence(comparison_expr,
                                [
                                    (and_operator, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                                    (or_operator, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT)
                                ])

result = grammar.parseString(query)
print(result.asList())
```

This gives me the following output:

```
[[['parent.name', '=', 'foo'], 'and', [['name', '=', 'bar'], 'or', ['age', '=', 11]]]]
```

Now I don't know what to do. How can I dynamically generate a SQLAlchemy query? Are there any libraries that could help with this? Would it be easier to generate raw SQL?

Comment: Your question shows effort and is not inherently bad, so personally I don't understand the downvote, but: it ticks some checkboxes of a "too broad" or "off-site resource request", which is why you're getting the close votes. Try rewording it a bit to a more specific direction and share at least some ideas you've floated how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the parser written is the first step. From here, I suggest you enhance your `operatorPrecedence` call (the name is old and deprecated btw, now called `infixNotation`) to have pyparsing build a nested set of nodes, which corresponds to building an abstract syntax tree (AST). While you have succeeded in getting a parser working, I must tell you that this next step is rather a big one.

The idea is to have the parser give you back not just strings or converted ints and floats, but actual class instances. It would look something like this:

```
class AndOperation:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        # tokens will look like [operand1, 'AND', operand2, 'AND', operand3, ...]
        self._operands = tokens[::2]

class OrOperation:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        # tokens will look like [operand1, 'OR', operand2, 'OR', operand3, ...]
        self._operands = tokens[::2]

class NotOperation:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        # tokens will look like ['NOT', operand]
        self._operands = tokens[-1]
```

Then you would add them to infixNotation as:

```
AND, OR, TRUE, FALSE = map(pp.Keyword, "AND OR TRUE FALSE".split())
boolean_term = TRUE | FALSE | ~(AND | OR) + pp.pyparsing_common.identifier
boolean_expr = pp.infixNotation(boolean_term,
    [
    ('NOT', 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, NotOperation),
    ('AND', 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, AndOperation),
    ('OR', 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, OrOperation),
    ])
```

Without the added class parse actions, parsing "P AND NOT Q" would return:

```
[['P', 'AND', ['NOT', 'Q']]]
```

With the added classes, parsing "P AND NOT Q" would give you something like:

```
[AndOperation('P', NotOperation('Q'))]
```

At this point you can choose whether you want to add some form of `evaluate()` or `execute` method to each xxxOperation class to evaluate the expression, or perhaps a `render` method if you wanted to just output an SQL WHERE clause.

For instance, `render` for AndOperation to create SQL WHERE syntax might look like:

```
def render(self):
    return ' AND '.join("'" + oper + "'" if isinstance(oper, str) else oper.render()
                                   for oper in self.operands)
```

(As Ilja Everilä notes in his comment, beware of SQL injection issues with actually *running* such a WHERE clause directly - `render()` would mostly be for visualization and debugging)

There are several examples in the pyparsing repo `examples` directory (https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/tree/master/examples) - search for uses of `infixNotation` to see how they are done.

Comment: I'd personally rather recommend rendering SQLAlchemy expression constructs (if possible), since `"'" + oper + "'"` seems rather error prone and possibly SQL injectiony.

Comment: Very good point - most of this code is contrived and simplified, and the answer is *still* pretty long. What you describe would be more in the `execute()`-type path. See edits.